# JavaScript Syntax not working

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have this code, which works pretty well :

```
var draw = [
      {lat:60.06484046010452,lng:-121.640625}, {lat:50.064191736659104,lng:-136.40625}, {lat:50.958426723359935,lng:-103.7109375}
    ];
```

But Now, as the Values of the Variable draw needs to be changed at the runtime, I Wrote this code & I expect it allow changing draw values as the Values of the variable st changes :

```
var st = "{lat:60.06484046010452,lng:-121.640625},{lat:50.064191736659104,lng:-136.40625},{lat:50.958426723359935,lng:-103.7109375}";
var draw =[ st ];
```

But this isn't working, How can i make it work, I'm a noob, thank you

Comment: st is of type String, you can only manipulate it as a text would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`st` is of type String, you can only manipulate it as a text would be.

I believe you are using objects wrong but you were using it right initially:

```
var draw = [{lat:60.06484046010452,lng:-121.640625}, {lat:50.064191736659104,lng:-136.40625}, {lat:50.958426723359935,lng:-103.7109375}];
```

Furthermore if you need to add objects to this array use the `push` method.

```
draw.push({ lat: 60.06484046010452, lng: -103.7109375 });
```

To remove from the end use the `pop` method:

```
var lastItem = draw.pop();
```

To add at the beginning use the unshift method and to remove use shift.

Answer (score 3):

You just turned your object into a string. Just keep it as an object, and it will work fine (a.k.a remove the quotes):

```
var st = '[{"lat":60.06484046010452,"lng":-121.640625},{"lat":50.064191736659104,"lng":-136.40625},{"lat":50.958426723359935,"lng":-103.7109375}]';
var draw = JSON.parse(st);
```

Comment: @Joe Your objects just need to be in different variables (or write it the way you did in your first code sample).

Comment: Actually, I'm running the JavaScript Using WebView and WebEngine JavaFX Classes, and One of the part of my program converts random sets of numbers, to the form i've written above and store's it as string, and pass it to javascript, so now splitting the string again, and modifying it would add more complexity

Comment: If you get it as a string, you can pass it directly (in the JSON format) and parse it into javascript, without splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code works and you can edit it. The `draw` variable will be a list of objects and you can add and delete items:

```js
var draw = [
      {lat:60.06484046010452,lng:-121.640625}, {lat:50.064191736659104,lng:-136.40625}, {lat:50.958426723359935,lng:-103.7109375}
    ];
draw.push({lat:10.10101010,lng:20.20202020});
for(var i = 0; i < draw.length; i++){
    document.write(draw[i].lat + " / " + draw[i].lng + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Add info regarding why the change in his code does not work. e.g. "st is of type String, you can only manipulate it as a text would be."